# How can the value of a javascript function argument survive across page requests?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, scope

I am looking into a bug in a site I've inherited, and my investigation has raised an interesting javascript scope question. Code below has been simplified to show only relevant details.

The generic service below has a problem where it sometimes returns no data after logout (in production only, of course). When that happens, we see the "data" argument to ApplyToolbarBindings is not null or an empty object -- it is actually hydrated with state from the previous page request. The state of that object survives through an asp.net postback, in other words, the net effect being that the toolbar shows a "known" user even after they have logged out.

```
function ApplyToolbarBindings(data) {
    if (!data.IsKnown) {
        jQuery("#ToolBar").attr("data-bind", 'template: { name: "AnonymousUserToolbarTemplate" }');
    } else {
        jQuery("#ToolBar").attr("data-bind", 'template: { name: "KnownUserToolbarTemplate" }');
    }
    ko.applyBindings(data, document.getElementById('ToolBar'));
}
function GetToolBarData(callbackFunction) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/Services/Toolbar/ToolBarService.ashx?v=' + toolbarV,
        success: callbackFunction,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
function loadToolbar() {
    GetToolBarUserData(ApplyToolbarBindings);
}
jQuery(function () { loadToolbar(); });
```

What is the lifecycle of an argument to a function when that function has been globally defined? Is this behavior because the ajax object state is unchanged when no data is returned?

Comment: the only way is to send whatever values you need by Get request to the target page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not JavaScript scope related; there is no such thing as scope-between-page-loads.

What you'll find is that the browser (or some device between the user and server) is caching the AJAX request to `'/Services/Toolbar/ToolBarService.ashx?v=' + toolbarV`.

You can get around this by using [the `cache: false` `jQuery.ajax` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) (which effectively adds a random string to the URL to stop it being cached), or by emitting correct `Cache-Control` headers (`no-cache`).

Comment: A coworker has given me pretty much the same answer, Matt. Thanks. We do have ajax caching enabled.

Answer (score 0):

On most servers you have session, application and request scope. Which means, that js scope is somewhere below request scope because it exists for a short time after the request was set and you get your response.

If you want a scoped value you could work with a template system and beans. (velocity, JSF or whatever). If not...

You can use cookies!

```
/**
 * deletes a cookie
 **/
function deleteCookie(c_name) {
    now = new Date();
    document.cookie=c_name+"=; expires="+now.toGMTString();
}

/**
 * sets a cookie
 **/
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

/**
 * Returns the cookie Value with unescaped content
 **/
function getCookie(c_name) {
    var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++) {
        x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
        y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
        if (x==c_name) {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
```